# dataset reads first column as data instead of header

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
jan = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\13475\\Desktop\\project\\Copy of Data_Jan_2021.csv')
feb = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\13475\\Desktop\\project\\Copy of Data_Feb_2021.csv')
mar = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\13475\\Desktop\\project\\Copy of Data_Mar_2021.csv')

df = pd.concat([jan, feb, mar], axis = 0)
```

I uploaded 3 files this way but when I run my codes I realized that it reads 1st column as data. How can I make the changes for it to only read the data below row 1. for example, when One of the column is state and under that it has NY, NJ, CT.... my program is reading column 'state" as one of the state input.

Comment: Please provide an example of your data as text to have a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

There are a parameter in the method "read_csv" that you can specify to use or not the first column as index.

You can use:

```
jan = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\13475\\Desktop\\project\\Copy of Data_Jan_2021.csv', index_col=False)
```

The `index_col=False` will force to not use the fisrt column as index.

Here the link to the pandas page:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying that the first row is a header, or you can also skip the first row:

```
jan = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\13475\\Desktop\\project\\Copy of Data_Jan_2021.csv', header=0)

jan = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\13475\\Desktop\\project\\Copy of Data_Jan_2021.csv', skiprows=1)
```